# Http Delete throws error response code 405 in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart, http-delete

I want to delete a contact using ID in my app. The request works fine on postman when I give the id directly in the link(i.e. static) but not with `$id` variable. And when trying to do that using HTTP request in Flutter it gives a 405 response code. The expected response code is 200.

I'm new to flutter and RestAPI so I don't know where I'm going wrong, I've also build a model `delectContactModel` using `quicktype.io`.

**Here's the error:**

```
 405
E/flutter (12820): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to delete contact.
E/flutter (12820): #0      API_Manager.deleteContact (package:app/services/api_manager.dart:100:7)
E/flutter (12820): <asynchronous suspension>
```

**API_Manager():**

```
    Future<DeleteContactModel> deleteContact(String id) async {
    String basicAuth = 'Basic examplebasicauthkey';
    final http.Response response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://example.com/api/contacts/$id/delete'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'authorization': basicAuth,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return DeleteContactModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to delete contact.');
    }
  }
```

**View:**

```
    TextEditingController id = TextEditingController();

    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        id.text = widget.contact.id.toString();
    }

    showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
        Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
          child: Text("Cancel"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        );
        Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
          child: Text("Delete"),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
           await API_Manager().deleteContact(id.text);   //Calling the delete function here
          },
        );
    
        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
          title: Text(firstName.text + " " + lastName.text),
          content: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?"),
          actions: [
            cancelButton,
            continueButton,
          ],
        );
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return alert;
          },
        );
      }
    
      void handleClick(String value) {
        switch (value) {
          case 'Edit':
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => EditContact()));
            break;
          case 'Delete':
            showAlertDialog(context);
            break;
        }
      }
```

**EDIT:**

Postman Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see the status is 200, but the problem here is that I have given the ID directly in the link, I don't know how to pass it as a variable `id`.

Comment: Http 405 means, you are not allowed to use that http method. Http methods are what we call GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH. Can you make sure that you are using the same method that you use on postman?

Comment: Are you sure your URL should have `/delete` at the end? Can you post a screenshot of it working in Postman?

Comment: Hi @Pionix, yes I am using the same method you can view the postman screenshot I attached in the question now

Comment: @RichardHeap yes the link is correct, you can view the postman screenshot I attached now in the end of the question

Comment: @ShreyasBhardwaj the API end need  to  check throughly when you request to delete. Most probably the issue is on API end

Comment: I see several things you can investigate. 1 - you are including a content-type in the request, but that's superfluous as you aren't including any content; 2 - are you sure that the basic auth value is correct? You can test that by removing the information from the auth tab of postman and adding it manually on the headers tab (it would have been useful to see the request headers tab in the screenshot); 3 - Dart always lower cases the header names, which confuses some servers. When testing for (2) above, be sure to use `authentication` rather than `Authentication` in Postman.